# Can you have multiple statements in cases of switch?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case

```
switch (other.gameObject.tag) {
            case "Electron":
                    elec = true;
                    pyst = other;
                    break;
            case "Proton":
                    prot = true;
                    pyst = other;
                    break;
            }
```

Seems pretty simple, but couldn't find the answer. The code is in c#, so will pyst = other; line be implemented as well as elec = true;?

Comment: What happens when you try it? Does it compile?

Comment: my code is very huge and complicated, it would take years to find out if it works, but in order for game to work correctly this one should be implemented. I'm sorry for this dumb basic question, but I couldn't find the answer on the net so can you answer? does every line between case and break is implemented or just the first one? They don't specify it anywhere so I just want to make sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

When the code enters a case block, it'll continue executing all commands until it reaches the `break` or say a `return` statement.

In some other languages, if you leave out the break it'll keep executing the rest of the commands (this causes a "Control cannot fall through from one case label" error in C#)